# Getting unique values from joining two tables in which one table might have repeated values for a particular column

Tags: sql

this is my first foray into SQL.

I have two tables Order & OrderItem.
Order has the OrderID as PK which is FK in OrderItem.

Now the OrderItem has 'ProductName' column which brings me to the question.

I need to get all the Products, the names specifically, placed between two dates. The Order table has the 'CreatedDate' column.

A given order can have the same Product multiple times.
So when you do this:

```
SELECT * FROM OrderItem
WHERE OrderID=40861
```

The result set may return 5 rows, all of them having the same value in the 'ProductName' column.

I wrote this query:

```
SELECT Order.OrderID OrderID, OrderItem.ProductName ProductName From Order
    INNER JOIN OrderItem ON Order.OrderID = OrderItem.OrderID
WHERE Order.CreatedDate between '2012-02-27' AND '2014-10-08'
```

The result has multiple rows with same 'ProductName' value.

So the question is how do I write the query to return the result set with only a single row for an order eventhough the Order might have multiple quantities of the same Product?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: can you show the data, your output and expected output ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to get unique result you have 2 ways:

1. Use DISTINCT keyword:

   `SELECT DISTINCT Order.OrderID OrderID, OrderItem.ProductName ProductName From Order
       INNER JOIN OrderItem ON Order.OrderID = OrderItem.OrderID
   WHERE Order.CreatedDate between '2012-02-27' AND '2014-10-08'`
2. Group result:

   `SELECT Order.OrderID OrderID, OrderItem.ProductName ProductName From Order
           INNER JOIN OrderItem ON Order.OrderID = OrderItem.OrderID
       WHERE Order.CreatedDate between '2012-02-27' AND '2014-10-08'
   Group By Order.OrderID, OrderItem.ProductName`

EDIT: Actually there could be more ways like UNION, but it is ugly and not preferable way of doing this:

```
`SELECT Order.OrderID OrderID, OrderItem.ProductName ProductName From Order
    INNER JOIN OrderItem ON Order.OrderID = OrderItem.OrderID
WHERE Order.CreatedDate between '2012-02-27' AND '2014-10-08'`
```

`UNION`

```
`SELECT Order.OrderID OrderID, OrderItem.ProductName ProductName From Order
    INNER JOIN OrderItem ON Order.OrderID = OrderItem.OrderID
WHERE Order.CreatedDate between '2012-02-27' AND '2014-10-08'`
```